# User Login Trace

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

There are many JBoss nodes and the same ear (Java EE application) is deployed into each node. In my application, the user can log into each individual node, and I want to trace if the same user logs in to different nodes. How I can trace it?

If there  is only one node, then I can trace with a global Map which has all users logged in. But I can't find a solution for different nodes. This can be done using a database, but I want not to use DB because of another constraint.

Any solution for this please?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select one of your nodes as a master. Each login registers the user with the master which in turn keeps a single list. This creates a single point of failure (SPOF), but it's possibly OK, if it's only for logging. With some effort you can eliminate the SPOF.
2. Use a multicasting library like [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/). So each node informs all other nodes after a login. All nodes contain a local list of logged-in users.
3. Use a JMS topic, and have an MDB listen on that topic on each node: After a login, a message is published on the topic, and each node may build a list of logged-in users (this idea was pointed out by Aash Maharoon in a comment, see below)
4. Using JBoss 7 consider [Infinispan](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/). It's built-in, and for your use case, it basically offers a cluster-aware `java.util.Map`. Internally it uses JGroups.

The first option could be implemented with some servlets (= without any additional libraries etc.). The 2nd one requires another library.

The 3rd option requires JMS (JBoss has a built-in JMS provider). If a node is down, it possibly misses some messages. If this is a problem, consider using durable topic subscriptions. Examples: [Pub-Sub](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/JMS_Examples-A_Pub_Sub_Example.html) (the sending part is relevant) and [MDB](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v4/html/mdb.html)

The 4th option even requires a "full-blown" module/service, but it offers the highest level of abstraction.

Comment: What if we use JMS instead of JGroup ? Is there any absolute advantages ?

Comment: @AashMaharoon Yes, why not. I took the liberty to add it to the answer. As it's built-in in every JBoss version, I put it on the 3rd place. As you have to manually manage the list, I personally would prefer Infinispan, but it's really not a big effort to manage that list. So yes, another valid option.

Comment: I have added two links. The implementation does not really differ between JBoss 4 and JBoss 7 (but using a newer JBoss version allows to use annotations). Anyway, just give it a try, and if you have a specifc JMS topic client/MDB problem, just post another question. I am observing the JMS tag.

Comment: Thank you very much for your info.. I use JBoss 4 .. any sample codes or any sample/documented projects available ? Also.. how about performance and the security of above mentioned solutions?

Comment: AFAIK the links are for JBoss 4. Performance does not matter, because it's only "small" data. If security is a concern, put the servers in a separate sub net. Otherwise I can't really tell, possibly the default JBoss remoting API and it's security is sufficient. You could encrypt the content of the messages.

Comment: Infinispan and JGroup cannot be used in my system as my app needs jre 1.5. Infinispan and JGroup need 1.6 JRE as of its documentation. :(